# How do I handle crashed MongoDB sessions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

I have a node application that does something like the following:

```
const session = client.startSession();

try {
    session.startTransaction();

    // call methods on collections while passing the session
    // wait a while (1)

    await session.commitTransaction();
} catch {
    startOver();
} finally {
    await session.endSession();
}
```

If something happens and the node application dies while it's waiting `(1)`, then the next time I start the application, I get into an infinite loop because `startOver()` gets called over and over again with the error:

> WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.

I expect that this is happening because the client didn't get a chance to commit the transaction or end the session before it got killed.

So I was wondering, is this the expected behavior?

And how do I solve this problem?

Ideally, the client would send the server a message to tell it that it's going to get disconnected, but that's not something it can always do. Maybe it gets killed, or crashes, or the machine it runs on gets restarted, or something else happens that's completely out of its control, etc.

Is there maybe a way to inform the server that, if it doesn't hear anything from the client for 5 seconds, then it should automatically abort the transaction? Or maybe the MongoDB server can be configured this way? Or maybe the MongoDB server can be configured to ping the client regularly to make sure it's still alive?

Or maybe there's a better solution to this problem?

Comment: The default transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds is 60, do the write conflicts continue longer than 2 minutes after the crash?

Comment: @Joe, I can't check right now unfortunately, but 1-2 minutes sounds about right. I'm using the default MongoDB configuration (I have the official 6.0.3 binary and I'm running it locally without any configuration).